# Gallery of divs with float-left

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float, gallery

In my case I have a popup "window" with a title and a close button which is controlled with some script. What I want to do is to put gallery of divs with left-float so when the screen resizes they will stacked accordingly (eg. in very small screens they will go just 1 under another) so that's why I think that float is the best option here.

I am not sure how to do it and I would like your help as I want it to be to the center covering a specific percentage of area (so it can be more responsive). I would like you to just tell me what steps I should follow.

I was thinking on making a custom class .gallery set float to left but I don't know how to set everything else in order to work nice.

[image]

HTML

```
  <script> document.write('<div class="js">'); </script>
<nav><ul><li id="buttonc"><a href="#">click</a></li></ul></nav>

<div class="vidar-bg">
    <div id="vidar">
<span>my divs<a href="#closevid" id="closevid">&#215;</a></span>
                   </div>
</div>
 <script>  document.write('</div>');  </script>
```

CSS

```
.js .vidar-bg{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;right:0;
    top:0;bottom:0;
    z-index:100;
    background-color:rgba(50,50,50,0.5);
    display:none;}

#vidar{ 
    position:absolute;
    top:50%; 
    left:50%;
    z-index:101;
    width:80%px;
    height:80%px;
    left:10%;right:10%;
    top:10%;bottom:10%;}


#vidar span{
    display: block;
    background:#5DC3A7;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff !important;
    background: #f00;
    z-index:100;}

    #closevid{
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 18px;}

#closevid:hover{color: #000;}
```

Live code here: http://codepen.io/mariomez/pen/OPBVxY

thank you all in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This CSS should do it:

```
.gallery-item {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #F00;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 150px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

Then you just have to add the following HTML to your page:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-item">DIV</div>
</div>
```

Actually, most of the CSS properties are there just to create the red square with centered white text in the image you provided. To do what you want you just need the float: left property like you said yourself.

Comment: thanks but the problem is that the gallery should be the container not the div itself. I want to add some other divs inside :/

Comment: the divs should behave like in the image. I don't know which one must have the float setting.. the container or the divs inside the container :/

Comment: No problem! I've changed my code to do what you need, it'll behave the same way. You need to add the float: left property to the divs that you want to float to the left, the container is just, well, a container :) Add as many divs with the class "gallery-item" as you want, and they'll all stack on the left. Then try resizing your browser window to make them rearrange.